# Using square retrofit library to make http requests

Tags: android, httprequest, gson, retrofit

I was using `loopj async http library to make http requests`, but after making researches `about android networking library` i found out that **`retrofit`** is better than volley, the fastet and the most reliable networking library out there.

I planned to change my codes to be suitable to work with `retrofit`..

Formerly, i used this method to make `HTTP requests` :

```
AsyncHttpClient AHC = new AsyncHttpClient();
        RequestParams param = new RequestParams();
        param.put("arg1", arg1);
        param.put("arg2", arg2);
        AHC.post("http://xxxxx.xxx.xxxx.xxxx", param,
                new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String content) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

The content i'm getting is `json type.`

I read that retrofit uses gson by default.. which is really faster i think.

Formerly i used to fill my inner database in that way :

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(content);
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    TD.CreatePostsTable(
            json.getString("id")}
```

How these methods will become in retrofit ?

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Don't you use a POJO when returning data from the server ? You simply iterate trough the json and save in your DB ?

Comment: @LeonardoFerrari Yes, why should i use a POJO?

Comment: It's a good practice and make your code easier for other to read. Simply iterating throug JSON's is hard to mantain and confuse !

Comment: @LeonardoFerrari thanks for the information and your help.. i'll accept your answer as soon as i understand the approach.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help! If you have any question just ask :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your post method:

```
@POST("/users/login")
    YOUR_RETURN_TYPE loginUser(@Field("arg1") String arg1,
                   @Field("arg2") String arg1);
```

And the Retrofit config:

```
new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint("http://your_url")
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL).build();
```

And I'd recommend this approach to use with Retrofit, using a Singleton :

```
private Map<String, Object> restInstances = new HashMap<String, Object>();
public <T> T getRescClient(Class<T> clazz) {
    T client = null;

    if ((client = (T) restInstances.get(clazz.getCanonicalName())) != null) {
        return client;
    }

    client = restAdapter.create(clazz);
    restInstances.put(clazz.getCanonicalName(), client);
    return client;
}
```

And then call this:

```
 restApiProvider.getRestClient(UserService.class).your_method()
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

Look at this implementation: https://github.com/UweTrottmann/tmdb-java

The Tmdb class builds different services. For example, MovieServices which has:

```
@GET("/movie/{id}")
Movie summary(
        @Path("id") int tmdbId
);
```

This method, will call /movie/{id} method to REST server which returns a JSON. The method will return a Movie object, where attributes has the same name as JSON keys.

```
public class Movie extends MediaBase implements TraktEntity {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -1543214252495012419L;

@SerializedName("tmdb_id") public int tmdbId;
public Integer plays;
@SerializedName("in_collection") public Boolean inCollection;
public Date released;
public String trailer;
public Integer runtime;
public String tagline;
public String overview;
public String certification;
public Boolean watched;

}
```

Comment: May be it is very difficult to use the first time. But them, is always equal.